# Connection Lost, Try To connect Odoo 10 Problem

Tags: docker, docker-compose, odoo-10, ubuntu-18.04

Hi There recently i just installed odoo 10 on my office server they using vps , everything went normal until i tried to create new record at any module its always showed like this for example

[image]
when i checked the log its showed something like

```
INFO admin odoo.http: /web/dataset/call_kw/res.partner/onchange: Invalid JSON data: '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"call","params":{"model":"res.partner","method":"onchange","args":[[],{"id":false,"active":true,"pos_order_count":0,"total_invoiced":0,"sale_order_count":0,"contracts_c.
```

if tried to add new sale order always onchange problem .

already try with docker, any docker, try to install manual, the results still same
Any Idea why?which port i must open for odoo so it can work normally because if i install it on my local everythings work fine

thank's

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to help someone who bumped into this question. I managed to solve it by adding the following to the odoo.config.

```
limit_time_cpu = 3600
limit_time_real = 3600
```

Comment: Ok I will try it now

Comment: i am having similar error when i try to upgrade muk_documents module from version 12 to 14